# Calling multiple methods on an object to get multiple values

Tags: ruby

Instead of:

```
v1 = obj.m1.m2.m3.m4
v2 = obj.m1.m2.m3.m5
```

I usually write like this to avoid calling the same methods:

```
tmp = obj.m1.m2.m3
v1 = tmp.m4
v2 = tmp.m5
```

But I think it's ugly to set a tmp var. I want to write briefly like this:

```
v1, v2 = obj.m1.m2.m3.{:m4, :m5}
```

Does ruby have similar syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is probably:

```
v1, v2 = obj.m1.m2.m3.instance_eval{[m4, m5]}
```

but it is not efficient, nor is it worth doing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
v = obj.m1.m2.m3
v1, v2 = [:m4, :m5].map { |m| v.send(m) }
```